# typescript make readonly properties writeable

Tags: typescript

I want to create the following test helper to simulate document key press events:

```
export const simulateKeyPress = (key: string) => {
  var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
  e.key = key;
  e.keyCode = e.key.charCodeAt(0);
  e.which = e.keyCode;
  e.ctrlKey = true;

  document.dispatchEvent(e);
};
```

but typescript complains:

> TypeError: Cannot set property key of [object KeyboardEvent] which has
>   only a getter

I've tried the following but I get the same error:

```
type Mutable<T extends { [x: string]: any }, K extends string> = { [P in K]: T[P] };

export const simulateKeyPress = (key: string) => {
  var e = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
  (e as Mutable<KeyboardEvent, keyof KeyboardEvent>).key = key;
  (e as Mutable<KeyboardEvent, keyof KeyboardEvent>).keyCode = e.key.charCodeAt(0);
  (e as Mutable<KeyboardEvent, keyof KeyboardEvent>).which = e.keyCode;
  (e as Mutable<KeyboardEvent, keyof KeyboardEvent>).ctrlKey = true;

  document.dispatchEvent(e);
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure why you are still getting the error, your approach should work, you can create a less verbose version of `Mutable` on versions `2.8` and higher:

```
type Mutable<T> = { -readonly [P in keyof T ]: T[P] };

export const simulateKeyPress = (key: string) => {
    var e: Mutable<KeyboardEvent> = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
    e.key = key;
    e.keyCode = e.key.charCodeAt(0);
    e.which = e.keyCode;
    e.ctrlKey = true;

    document.dispatchEvent(e);
};
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Mutable%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20-readonly%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%20%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20const%20simulateKeyPress%20%3D%20(key%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20e%3A%20Mutable%3CKeyboardEvent%3E%20%3D%20new%20KeyboardEvent('keydown')%3B%0D%0A%20%20e.key%20%3D%20key%3B%0D%0A%20%20e.keyCode%20%3D%20e.key.charCodeAt(0)%3B%0D%0A%20%20e.which%20%3D%20e.keyCode%3B%0D%0A%20%20e.ctrlKey%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20document.dispatchEvent(e)%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B)